# xterm login prompt not gnome login prompt

Tags: debian, login, xterm

instead of loading `gdm3` when i turn my pc on, i want to load into an xterm with just a window manager (no desktop environment) and i want the xterm to have the login prompt as its first action so that i can login as my user within the xterm. i have the following info in my .xinitrc file:

```
$ ls -la .xsession
lrwxrwxrwx 1 peter peter 8 Oct  7 18:25 .xsession -> .xinitrc
$ cat .xinitrc 
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
xterm -maximized &
exec mutter
```

but this only runs once i login through gnome. i really just want to turn off gnome and run an xterm instead. i'm guessing i will need to modify my `/etc/X11/Xsession` or my `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` file to get rid of the `gdm3 start` and replace it with something. what should i add/remove from these files? i want to bring up a login prompt within the xterm as the first action.

i'm on debian 7 and currently have gnome3 desktop environment with mutter window manager

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the gdm service:

```
service gdm disable
```

If `gdm` is what it's called (it should be a shell script in `/etc/init.d`).

This will mean you boot to console.  To try starting X using your xinit, use `startx`.

You do have to log in before you do that, of course.  If you don't use xdm/gdm, then you'll have to do it at the console.  If you then want X to start automatically, you could try adding `startx` to the end of `~/.profile`, but I recommend you just type it manually.

*[Note this is the current method for **Debian** and not necessarily other distros.]*

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve a very similar effect is to boot into the console using grub and then run startx on login. just set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`.

then put the following at the bottom of `~/.bashrc`:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]] && startx
```

this ensures that when the user logs in through virtual console tty1 only then x will start and then the `~/.xinitrc` script will run.